# dispatch_apply with local variable declaration doesn't compile in C++ method implementation

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

The code

```
class XXX
{
   vector<Record> getAll()
   {
      dispatch_apply(3, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ...; ++j)
        { ... }
      });
    }
}
```

doesn't compile, saying "'int XXX::j' is not a static member of 'class". The [doc on blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW2) says "Local variables declared within the lexical scope of the block, which behave exactly like local variables in a function. " The file has .mm extension. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, and clang will compile it.   In general clang's C++ blocks support is a lot better then gcc's, and you want to use it if you can.   If you need to use gcc there is a workaround, use ::j to refer to j.   However that is illegal C++ and clang will choke on it, so you might want to make it conditional on what compiler is involved...